# count the number of turtles runs through sections

Tags: netlogo

I'm writing program. I want to count the number of turtles move through one cross, but I do not know what comma[image]nds can count the number of turtles in each section?

Comment: Are the grey rectangles the turtles and the black line the crossing point? What do you mean by 'move through'? (1) At the time being asked, the black line falls on the turtle (like in the top line)? OR (2) In the previous tick, the back edge was to the left of the line and this tick it is to the right of the line (assuming moving right)? OR (3) something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the xcor of the intersection, then

```
count turtles with [xcor = section-xcor]
```

Comment: if I want to print the results as Excel, then I should do?

Comment: You should post this as a separate question, if it hasn't already been asked.  I think it has been asked and answered.  You probably want to write a CSV file.  Excel can read CSV files.